# Copying a Gedit Syntax Highlighting .lang File

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, syntax-highlighting, gedit

I installed Gedit on my Windows machine since I've grown very accustomed to it on my Linux box.

I am writing some VBScript files and since there was no Syntax already configured for VBScript, I've been using the VB.NET syntax highlighting instead, which is good enough for me.

In order to have this highlighting automatically applied to my ***.vbs** script files, I copied "vbnet.lang" to "vbs.lang". Then, I modified the following lines:

**From This:**

```
    <language id="vbnet" _name="VB.NET" version="2.0" _section="Sources">
      <metadata>
        <property name="mimetypes">text/x-vbnet;text/x-vb</property>
        <property name="globs">*.vb</property>
        <property name="line-comment-start">'</property>
      </metadata>
```

**To This:**

```
    <language id="vbs" _name="VBScript" version="2.0" _section="Scripts">
      <metadata>
        <property name="mimetypes">application/x-vbs;text/vbs;text/vbscript</property>
        <property name="globs">*.vbs</property>
        <property name="line-comment-start">'</property>
      </metadata>
```

So whenever I open a file with the extension ***.vbs** I can see Gedit applying the "VBScript" syntax highlighting to it by seeing "VBScript" selected on the bottom status bar of Gedit or by looking in:

```
View > Highlighting Mode > Scripts
```

and seeing that *VBScript is selected. However, nothing is changing and it still looks like plain text. If I switch the Highlighting Mode of the .vbs file manually to the VB.NET one the highlighting is applied just fine.

Any idea why this isn't working correctly even though it is recognizing the file extension and correctly assigning it to the **VBScript** Syntax Highlighting? I tried changing the vbs.lang file back to *"Sources"* to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't.